# How to fix Windows 2019 server to update time and date from Internet?

Tags: windows-server-2019

I am trying to sync my win server 2019 date and time from Internet, however I am getting the following error.

Does anybody have any clue about the cause of this error?

I have a Windows 2019 server VPS and is not a member of any domains.

[image]

Comment: You must supply additional information.  For instance are you able to ping `time.nist.gov`?  If you change the time server to some other server does it work?  Based on the error message, your VPS recently sucessfully synchronized the time, I based this on fact it's currently 19:00 UCT on 10/30/2019

Comment: I cannot ping that address.

Comment: Do you have any other addresses to test or use as an alternative?

Comment: No, I don't keep a list of alternatives, at my disposal since I have never encountered a case where `time.nist.gov` and/or my own time server wasn't accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing with different time servers, finally found a simple tool that saved my day:
[neutron](http://keir.net/neutron.html)

[image]

I managed to synchronize my server's time using this tool! Fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

The NIST is having [problems](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2184006-nist-down)
with funding and may have become unreliable.

I have just tested it with the website
[NTP Server Online Tester](https://servertest.online/ntp)
for `time.nist.gov` and saw that IPv4 was down but IPv6 was operational.
If you are on IPv4, then this is your problem.

You might have a look at some alternatives from Microsoft's
[A list of the Simple Network Time Protocol (SNTP) time servers that are available on the Internet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/262680/a-list-of-the-simple-network-time-protocol-sntp-time-servers-that-are).

I tested for example
[pool.ntp.org](https://www.ntppool.org/en/)
on the Online Tester, and the results were excellent.

EDIT: After tests by the poster with the
[neutron](http://keir.net/neutron.html)
time agent that uses the Standard Time Protocol on UDP port 37, rather than
the Simple Network Time Protocol (SNTP) on UDP port 123, the problem seems
to be that some firewall is blocking the widely-used port 123.

Anyone experiencing the same problem should first check his firewall and also
get in touch with the Support of his provider, for verifying if this is indeed
the problem.

Comment: I have IPv6 enabled in adapter settings.

Comment: I tested pool.ntp.org and got the same failure result

Comment: Quote: "Neutron uses the standard Time protocol (UDP port 37). See RFC 868 for more details. It is not an SNTP (UDP port 123) client.". It seems like some firewall is blocking port 123. You should check your local firewall and also ask the VPS provider if their firewall is blocking it.

Comment: Does it make any difference in the end result if I use neutron? Any downsides?

Comment: You are the only judge of that. I would try to avoid a third party product if I could do it easily.

Comment: @acman123: The practical downsides are that there are _far fewer_  RFC 868 Time servers on the Internet than there are NTP servers, so if one goes down you don't have much of a replacement (it could even be that NIST are the only ones who still provide such a service), and the Time protocol itself will  become impossible to use beyond 2038, which makes Neutron a short-term solution. (The protocol also has much lower accuracy than NTP or even SNTP, since it cannot account for network latency at all; that's fine for desktops but would make it unsuitable for servers.)

Comment: Can I use any kind of a vpn software to bypass such a firewall ?

Comment: Yes, in most cases a VPN can bypass any firewall.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (tick the V sign). See [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for an explanation of why this is important.